# How can get xamarin.Android value in PCL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I Created a custom map in xamarin android and implement map move event

```
private async void NativeMap_CameraIdle(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var LatLng = NativeMap.CameraPosition.Target;
    var address = await Geocode.GetAddress(LatLng.Latitude.ToString(), LatLng.Longitude.ToString(), "en");
    string add = address.FormattedAddress;
    string con = address.Country;
}
```

this method every time when i move map and getting address

> string add= address.FormattedAddress;
>   string con = address.Country;

i want to value add and con in label text and reflect label text every time when move map, how can fix this

Comment: You need to improve your English to make the question readable, this is very confusing aside from major grammar problems.

Comment: @IvanIčin I know my english is bad

Comment: a) create a custom event that is raised whenever a location is found, or b) use MessagingCenter to pass a message

Comment: Dependency Injection or Messaging Service